# mkgroup command not found on Ec2 RedHat?

Tags: redhat, groups

I'm converting some environment scripts from Ubuntu to Red Hat 6.5. The mkgroup command for adding user groups seems to be not found:

```
[the-user@xxxxxxxxx ~]$ mkgroup myGroup
mkgroup: command not found
```

What does a guiless RedHat use for group management?  I thought mkgroup/lsgroup/etc were Linux standards?

Comment: I've never heard of such commands in Linux, and as far as I can tell neither has Google. They are certainly not standard.

Comment: man mkgroup and a google for man mkgroup returned reasonable results. Apologies for the newbie assumptions.

Comment: Ubuntu does a _lot_ of nonstandard stuff. Which is one of _many_ reasons you should avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `groupadd`.

The *standard* Linux commands for user and group management (from shadow-utils) are:

```
/usr/bin/chage
/usr/bin/gpasswd
/usr/bin/lastlog
/usr/bin/newgrp
/usr/bin/sg
/usr/sbin/adduser
/usr/sbin/chpasswd
/usr/sbin/groupadd
/usr/sbin/groupdel
/usr/sbin/groupmems
/usr/sbin/groupmod
/usr/sbin/grpck
/usr/sbin/grpconv
/usr/sbin/grpunconv
/usr/sbin/newusers
/usr/sbin/pwck
/usr/sbin/pwconv
/usr/sbin/pwunconv
/usr/sbin/useradd
/usr/sbin/userdel
/usr/sbin/usermod
/usr/sbin/vigr
/usr/sbin/vipw
```

See their respective man pages for more.